# Run C++ file with input in Sublime Text 2

Tags: c++, sublimetext2

After compilation of C++ source code, I want to run it with an input file through the sublime text command. How can this be done?

Comment: Set up an appropriate [build system](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) in the [project settings](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean a parameter after your C++ build file, I have found a way to do this in a dodgy way... I created a new build system for c++11 and added the input file (see input_file below) to the Run section.

```
{
"cmd": ["g++", "-Wall", "-Wextra", "-pedantic", "-std=c++0x",   "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++0x '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' input_file"]
    }
]}
```

Save the file, as for example `C++11.sublime-build`, in `$HOME/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User`. Choose as Build System C++11 and it should do the job.